# R summary function within cat function causing issues

Tags: r

I'm having trouble printing out the summary of linear regression model with cat function to a text file. The line of code producing the error

```
cat(summary(model), file = "results.txt", sep = "\n")
```

This line produces an error:

`argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'`

I can't figure out a way to fix this. What is causing this?

Comment: `cat` is meant for simpler data structures, it can't handle lists nor df's.

Comment: You can try: `cat(capture.output(summary(x)), file = "results.txt", sep = "\n")`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `capture.output` solution.

```
model <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, iris)
capture.output(summary(model), file = "results.txt")
```